# PDF Validation, not just text but fonts and footer/header size

Tags: selenium, validation, pdf, fonts, shapes

I am trying to validate a pdf using selenium,but I am not sure if there is an API that I can use. I am using pdfbox to validate text and that's doable.However, I want to verify the font size, boldness/italic, shapes and shapes locations, footer, header size..etc. I hope you got my point. If you know any library please let me know. Appreciated.

Comment: You could use Selenium to download the PDF, but you will need to validate it with another library or service like PDFSharp.

Comment: You mention that you already use pdfbox to validate text. Why don't you use it for the other stuff, too?

Comment: I tried but it does`t support the things I want. Or may be I couldn`t do it. have you done such a validations with pdfbox?